# Add subtitle to center of pie-chart in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, ios-charts

I want to display a subtitle below my main text in the center of the pie chart to let users know what the number represents. Is this possible? Right now I have a number that I converted to a string.

Below is my code:

```
func setCenter(days: Int){

    let circleColor = UIColor.black
    var textColor = UIColor.white

    pieChart.holeRadiusPercent = 0.3
    pieChart.transparentCircleRadiusPercent = 0.0
    let dayString = String(describing: days)
    let centerText = NSAttributedString(string: dayString , attributes: [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName:textColor,NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SubwayLogo",size:30)!])
    pieChart.centerAttributedText = centerText
    pieChart.centerTextRadiusPercent = 1.0
    pieChart.holeColor = circleColor
}
```

Let me know if you need to see other parts of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm, I figured it out. You have to create 2 mutable attributed strings and then concatenate them with the second having a "\n"

```
func setCenter(days: Int){

    let circleColor = UIColor.black
    let textColor = UIColor.white

    pieChart.holeRadiusPercent = 0.3
    pieChart.transparentCircleRadiusPercent = 0.0
    let dayString = String(describing: days)
    let centerText = NSMutableAttributedString()
    let numberText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " " + dayString, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:textColor,NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SubwayLogo",size:30)!])
    let descriptionText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n Days Left", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:textColor,NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SubwayLogo",size:8)!])
    centerText.append(numberText)
    centerText.append(descriptionText)
    pieChart.centerAttributedText = centerText
    pieChart.centerTextRadiusPercent = 1.0
    pieChart.holeColor = circleColor
}
```

Make sure to play around with the spacing and sizes of the 2 mutable strings. I added an extra space before dayString to get it to align, pieChart is a little finicky.